# Powershell: Swap columns and rows in a DataGrid (Or something better)

Tags: powershell, arraylist, datagrid

Using a datagrid in a powershell form.  I would like to swap columns and rows, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I don't seem to understand ArrayLists enough to manually swap out the values to a new ArrayList, or Arrays in general.

This was so much easier in VBS, I understood how arrays worked there. =/

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$procInfo = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq "SomeUsername"} -Properties PasswordLastSet,CanonicalName |Select-Object Name,@{n='PasswordLastSet';e={[math]::Round((NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $_.PasswordLastSet).TotalDays,2)}},@{n='OU Path';e={$_.CanonicalName -replace '^.*?/(.*)/.*?$','$1'}}
$array.Add($procInfo)
$dataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid 
$dataGrid1.DataSource = $array
```

Comment: Arrays work the (exact) same way as in VBS. Not the exact same way, but the same way. Comparing ArrayLists with Array is nearly like Comparing Cars with Carports. Java with JavaScript. And so on...

Comment: Okay, how do you create a sub-array in VBS and how do you create a multidimensional array in Powershell?

Then how do you input an array into a DataGrid?

Comment: Like `Dim array(1,4)`? If you want guidance on vbs, please add a new question with the according tags. If you want to know how to do this in posh, why didn't you ask? It should be `@(@())`, but I'm not sure